# Bolding Lines in R Table, as a way to group two rows

Tags: r

I have this sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)    # or dplyr 
library(formattable)

odds <- tibble(
  League = c("NHL", "NHL", "NHL", "NHL"),
  Team = c("Toronto", "New Jersey", "Anaheim", "Florida"),
  Odds = c("-110", "+105", "+105", "-125")
)
```

I've found a lot of answers for bolding the actual table content, rows, columns, headers, etc. What I'm trying to do is bold the lines around every matchup in the table.

Eg, `Toronto` is playing `New Jersey`, and I want to highlight that those two rows should be looked at as one item. I want to bold the box around those two rows. Or do **something** that makes it obvious that those two teams are playing each other.

I found the `formattable` package, which is great. Love it. And it separates headers excellently. But not sure how to highlight each pairing.